# Trying to put two javascripts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to put two `onClick` functions, but when i put them together I get an error. And first function ain't working, here is my script. As you can see im trying to call `insertData` function and then reload page with this function `window.location.reload()`. Bellow the script there is photo with an error.

```
if ($canEdit) {
        $s .= ("\n\t\t".'<a href="#">'
               . "\n\t\t\t".'<img src="./images/icons/tick.png" alt="' . $AppUI->_('Check') 
               . '" border="0" width="12" height="12" onClick="javascript:insertData('. $currentTasken .', '.$currentUser.', \''.$currentSummary.'\', '.$currentPercent.', \''.$currentDescription.'\'); window.location.reload();" />' . "\n\t\t</a>");
    }
    $s .= "\n\t</td>";
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Note that you should use `json_encode` to make sure the data is escaped properly.
    var currentTasken = <?php echo json_encode($currentTasken=$a['task_id']); ?>;
    var currentUser = <?php echo json_encode($currentUser=$AppUI->user_id); ?>;
    var currentSummary = <?php echo json_encode($currentSummary=$row[0]); ?>;

    function insertData(currentTasken, currentUser, currentSummary, currentPercent, currentDescription)
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","modules/tasks/datafile.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        // Here, use the JS variables but, likewise, make sure they are escaped properly with `encodeURIComponent`
        xmlhttp.send("currentUser=" + encodeURIComponent(currentUser) + "&currentTasken=" + encodeURIComponent(currentTasken) + "&currentSummary=" + encodeURIComponent(currentSummary) + "&currentPercent=" + encodeURIComponent(currentPercent)+ "&currentDescription=" + encodeURIComponent(currentDescription));
    }

    </script>
```

Here is the photo of the error:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the response of the request?

Comment: Should i put some code into script to show you the response?

Comment: The screenshot you posted shows (part of) the request. The response should be right below it.

Comment: http://s2.postimg.org/4t460a6ix/Untitled2.png Here is the bellow

Comment: Ok, I guess that means the request is failing with no response. Can you look on the server to see what is wrong? Check error logs, maybe the access log, you should be able to find at least a statuscode there.

Comment: But i know that the problem is because of that `window.location.reload()`

Comment: Ah, so you're aborting the request. Umm, don't abort the request? ie. delay execution of the `reload` until the request has finished. The reload seems a little bit odd here, as you can see ajax doesn't play well with page reloads. The ideal situation would be that can subvert the need to reload by changing (with ajax) the parts of the page that need to be changed.

Comment: But how can i do both functions? Coz i need to reload page after pressing that button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onClick="javascript:doClickStuff('. $currentTasken .', '.$currentUser.', \''.$currentSummary.'\', '.$currentPercent.', \''.$currentDescription.'\');"
```

Make you click function call the two functions and then set that as the click event

```
function doClickStuff(data){
   insertData(data);
}
function insertData(currentTasken, currentUser, currentSummary, currentPercent, currentDescription)
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","modules/tasks/datafile.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

           //callback to reload page
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
             window.location.reload();
           }
        }; 
            // Here, use the JS variables but, likewise, make sure they are escaped properly with `encodeURIComponent`
        xmlhttp.send("currentUser=" + encodeURIComponent(currentUser) + "&currentTasken=" + encodeURIComponent(currentTasken) + "&currentSummary=" + encodeURIComponent(currentSummary) + "&currentPercent=" + encodeURIComponent(currentPercent)+ "&currentDescription=" + encodeURIComponent(currentDescription));
    }
```

Comment: Okay I've updated it so that it calls `window.location.reload()` in a success callback. See if that works